# BS23 Cipher Puzzle

Tags: cipher, visual

You guys solved [my last cipher puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52679/pixel-cipher-puzzle) remarkably quickly; here's a harder one to mull over.

You are given the following plaintext/ciphertext pairs:

> (TRANSCRIPTION:)
>
> ^X++.O+-O+X-+.-O+|.XX+|.X++.-
>
> O+|.X+|.O|X++-X|.X+|X+|.O+|.-O+X-.O+-
>
> O+X+|.+-.OX.-X.O|.-.-+-.OX.-X+|.+|-
>
> O|+.|.X|.X+|.X+|X.X+|+|.!
>
> [image: image 1]
>   Let the whole world know that today is a day of reckoning.

> (TRANSCRIPTION:)
>
> ^|O+.O+-X-+.O|-+O|+..X+.O|.-
>
> +|.X.O+|+.-X-+.O|-O+|.X.X+|+|.O|.,
>
> .X+|+-O|.X-+.-+|X+X.+.O|.-O+X+|.-.-
>
> O-X+-.|.+.-O+|.X-+.O|+.-O|.X-+.O|.-
>
> X+X+|.O+|+.+!
>
> [image: image 2]
>   But her dreams give her wings, and she flies to a place where shes loved.

> (TRANSCRIPTION:)
>
> ^.X+|X+|.O+X-+.O|-|O|O+.X.O|.+.-O+X+|.-
>
> O+O|OX.0.X+|+-XX.++.,
>
> .X+|X+|.O+X-+.O|>.X+X.|X.-O+X+|.-
>
> O+|.O|X.O++.!
>
> ^.X+|X+|.O+X-+.O|-X+X+|.X+|+.X+OX.-
>
> XX.+|.XO+|..Ox.-X.X+|-O+X-+.-
>
> |X+-.|.X|.-X+|.+|-X+|X.+|.XO+!
>
> [image: image 3]
>   Another bruise to try and hide,
>   another alibi to write.
>   Another lonely highway in the
>   black of night.

Derive the plaintext that corresponds to the following cipher text:

> (TRANSCRIPTION:)
>
> ^|O+.O+-OX.X+|.O+.X+X+>.X+O+|..OX.O|.-
>
> |+.-X+.OX.-X-+.O|X+|., +.O+|+.X+|-
>
> O+XX+|.O+.+|.X-OX.X+|.O+.O+|+.-
>
> X+X+|.O|.O+-OX.X+|.O+.O|-X+.X.X+|+!
>
> [image: image 4]

Comment: Can we have a transcription? This seems tedious to transcribe.

Comment: @Deusovi Sure, though it'll take me a bit; give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Deusovi I just finished the first transcript; that should give you something to work with as I work on the others.

Comment: @Deusovi Transcripts are done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how it works:

> Letters are converted into numbers in the usual A1Z26 way. Each number is expressed as a sum of powers of 2 in descending order and these are converted into symbols: O=16, X=8, +=4, |=2, .=1. The horizontal bar (which I suppose we should consider as a zero) indicates a space but is also used to separate groups that would otherwise be ambiguous: e.g., TA can't be written as `O+.` because that would mean U and must instead be written `O+-.`. When there is a word-break *and* a "heavier" symbol is followed by a "lighter", a right-arrow is used instead of a horizontal bar. And of course the up-arrow is used to preface a capital letter.

I'm not very happy with my explanation of the horizontal bar and right-arrow there, so let me try again.

> Say that a "word break" occurs between letters when there is a space in the plaintext, and that a "bit break" occurs when the first letter's last symbol is "heavier" than the second letter's first. In either of these cases we need an explicit marker of the separation between letters. We use a horizontal bar when just one of these things occurs (and can therefore tell when it denotes an actual space by looking at the symbols on either side), and a right-arrow when both do (so it always denotes an actual space).

The last message says:

> But youll always be my hero, even though youve lost your mind.

(Regrettably, there is no encoding for apostrophes.)

Comment: I'm wholeheartedly impressed at how fast you solved this one.

Comment: There's two symbols that you haven't quite figured out: the up arrow, and the right arrow.

Comment: It was obvious very quickly that (1) this was probably a substitution cipher, (2) there were multiple symbols per letter, and (3) different letters had symbols of different lengths. I actually noticed the "adding a dot gives one letter later" pattern some time ago but didn't have the courage of my convictions :-).

Comment: Oh, sorry, the up-arrow was actually the first thing I worked out and I forgot to mention it. Will fix.

Comment: ... Fixed. (And fixed up the upper/lower case relationships in the transcription. I have a habit of putting things in all-caps, which was not appropriate here.)

Comment: Should I reveal the exact mechanics of the right arrow, or are you still interested in figuring that out yourself?

Comment: From the small number of occurrences it looks to me as if it's interchangeable with the horizontal bar. In particular, each of them is used at least one where there *is* a space, and at least once for mere disambiguation. I'm sure I'm missing something, but it's 4am local time and I need to go to bed. Feel free to reveal it; if not, I'll take another look tomorrow.

Comment: OK, I had another look. One claim in my previous comment is wrong. I believe my answer now gives a correct account of how those two symbols are used.

Comment: Your refined understanding is correct.  I imagine the fact that you went to sleep helped you out considerably.

Comment: It often does :-).